# Split HTML content to show more content

Tags: html, grid, gallery, portfolio

i am making a portfolio for my website but i want to make the same thing as [Humble Bundle (Example)](https://www.humblebundle.com/mobile)

When you pick one of the games the cellphone split in two parts and shows more info about the game, do you know any library that could help me?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use frames.  They load html files in a sort of split-screen view.  For example:

```
<frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
  <frame src="frame_a.htm">
  <frame src="frame_b.htm">
  <frame src="frame_c.htm">
</frameset>
```

All the frames go in a frameset and each frame loads a different html page.  This way you can load different things on the same page and they will be displayed in different sections of that page.